# Best way to handle this error? [AVCaptureFigVideoDevice setTorchModeOnWithLevel:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, flashlight, avcapturedevice, respondstoselector

I'm trying to turn off an image in my torch app if the device doesn't support LED dimming.

```
  NSError* outError;
        BOOL success = [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:brightnessLevel error:&outError];
        if(!success){
            [self.lightDialIndicator setHidden: YES];
            self.lightDial.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"light_dial_disabled.png"];
        }
```

but my app crashed with the following error

```
[AVCaptureFigVideoDevice setTorchModeOnWithLevel:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x73ad460
```

Any idea of a better/working way of detecting when the device doesn't allow me to use `setTorchModeOnWithLevel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `setTorchModeOnWithLevel` is a property on the `AVCaptureDevice` class.

Second, if you want to test if a class can respond to a certain selector that you're calling on it, you use this:

```
BOOL isSuccessful = NO;
if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(setTorchModeOnWithLevel:error:)]) {
    NSError* outError;
    isSuccessful = [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:brightnessLevel error:&outError];
}
if (!isSuccessful) {
    [self.lightDialIndicator setHidden: YES];
     self.lightDial.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"light_dial_disabled.png"];
}
```

You didn't show how you instantiated `device` in your example, but this applies to any class where you're unsure of whether it has a certain method or not.